# python - Sum of digits in 2^1000?

Tags: python

This is my code in python but the answer it gives is not correct according to projecteuler.net.

```
a = 2**1000
total = 0
while a >= 1:
    temp = a % 10
    total = total + temp
    a = int(a/10)
print(total)
```

It gives an output 1189. Am I making some mistake?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-sum-of-the-digits-of-2-1000)

Comment: @abccd That question is relevant, and there's good info there in the answers and comments, but I don't think it's close enough to this question to use it as a duplicate target.

Comment: @PM2Ring your answer's great. When I left the link, I was hoping to see if the community think if it's a dupe if not, a relevant post. I guess the verdict (at least by two other voters) was it's a close-enough dupe. Feel free to spark a reopen vote:)

Comment: @abccd I could re-open it by myself. It doesn't bother me too much that others wanted to close it with that dupe target, although I'd prefer it if a better matching question was the target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your logic is fine. The problem is that `2 ** 1000` is too big for all the digits to fit into a float, so the number gets rounded when you do `a = int(a/10)`. A Python `float` only has 53 bits of precision, you can read about it in the official tutorial article: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), and on Wikipedia: [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Also see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

This is `2 ** 1000`

> 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376

But `print(format(2**1000 / 10, 'f'))` gives us this:

> 1071508607186267380429101388171324322483904737701556012694158454746129413355810495130824665231870799934327252763807170417136096893411236061781867579266085792026680021578208129860941078404632071895251811587214122307926025420797364998626502669722909817741077261714977537247847201331018951634334519394304.000000

You can see that the digits start going wrong after `10715086071862673`.

So you need to use integer arithmetic, which in Python has arbitrary precision (only limited by how much memory Python can access). To do that, use the `//` [floor division](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-floor-division) operator.

```
a = 2**1000
total = 0
while a >= 1:
    temp = a % 10
    total = total + temp
    a = a // 10
print(total)
```

**output**

```
1366
```

We can condense that code a little by using [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) operators.

```
a = 2**1000
total = 0
while a:
    total += a % 10
    a //= 10
print(total)
```

---

Here's a faster way. Convert `a` to a string then convert each digit back to `int` and sum them. I use bit shifting to compute `a` because it's faster than exponentiation.

```
print(sum(int(u) for u in str(1 << 1000)))
```

Comment: Won't any errors or warning be shown? It's an overflow, right?

Comment: @J...S: Python ints are arbitrary-precision.

Comment: @user2357112 But PM said something about number being too big to fit in a  float.

Comment: @J...S 2**1000 is not too large in magnitude for a float in python, but it does require more bits to store exactly than a python float provides, so the result is erroneous but does not throw an exception.

Comment: @DillonDavis Meaning there will be an precision error or something?

Comment: @J...S When we do `2 ** 1000` or `1 << 1000` only integer arithmetic is involved, so we don't have any problems with overflow.

Comment: @J...S there exists no precision exception AFAIK. It will just return the incorrect / approximate value in all further arithmetic operations.

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand that now. But can you tell me why the `float` version is different?

Comment: @J...S By example: `val = (1 << 1000) / 1.0` => `1.0715086071862673e+301`,  `val + 1` => `1.0715086071862673e+301`, no errors thrown.

Comment: @J...S Because a float can only hold 53 bits of precision, which is  not enough to accurately represent a number with 1001 bits.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps clarify that floating point arithmetic is limited precision by definition. There would be a warning for nearly every floating-point operation if we were to receive warnings for rounding.

Comment: @tripleee Good idea, I've added a little more info & a couple of links, but I don't want to turn this answer into a tutorial on floating-point.